# Как сохранить состояние приложения в файл, для последующего считывания?

Tags: c++

Как сохранить состояние приложения (значения нескольких переменных строкового, целочисленного, и булевого типа) в файл (ini), например, и считать эти значения из файла.
С++ Builder 6. Желательно, чтоб файл с настройками лежал не рядом с екезешником, а в "моих документах" текущего пользователя.

Comment: а что Вам мешает так сделать?

Comment: Абсолютное неумение это делать. Чтож, если чтоб показать это на примере хотя бы с 1 переменной, понадобится очень много кода, не строит утруждать себя, я так или иначе сам научусь этому. Рано или поздно.

Answer (score 2):

Если количество сохраняемых параметров постоянное, то можно их просто сохранять как строки в определенном порядке при помощи filestream или fputs (fprintf) - на выбор. При чтении последовательно читаете строки, переводите строковые значения в переменную нужного типа и далее с ними работаете.

Если количество параметров точно не известно, можно в начале строки писать вид параметра, а потом его значение. При чтении парсите каждую строку.

Хотя, как мне кажется, вид файлов ini зафиксирован, можно найти и ознакомиться. Но принцип создания тот же - создаете строку нужного содержания и записываете в файл.

Возможно, есть  в билдере какой-то стандартный компонент по работе с ini-файлами.

Comment: Количество переменных строго постоянное, изменяться может только содержание.
За функции спасибо.

Comment: Если число сохраняемых параметров невелико и сами они не занимают много места, можно все сохранить в одну строку и далее считывать fscanf. Можно также применить смешанный подход.

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы, я нашел вот такое, думаю тут достаточно информации для решения этой задачи. http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread81496.html

Comment: Как вариант можно сохранять в файл данные в бинарном виде функцией fwrite и загружать оттуда функцией fread. Плюс этого метода - данные хранятся точно в том же виде, как они хранились в памяти, например при сохранении чисел с плавающей точкой не происходит перевода в десятичную систему и отсечения "лишних" знаков после запятой.

Comment: @insolor, тоже вариант. Только при сохранении в текстовом файле есть возможность при необходимости поправить файл ручками.

Comment: При умении пользоваться хекс-редактором можно подправить и бинарный файл:)

Comment: Можно, если хорошо знаешь структуру. А в текстовом можно комментарии наладить или имена полей информативные использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Для C++ Builder (не помню какая версия) есть свой класс

```
TIniFile *file = new TIniFile("name.ini");
```

Во время старта

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    TIniFile *file = new TIniFile("name.ini");

    something = file->ReadInteger("Something", "something", 250);

    delete file;
}
```

Во время закрытия

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
    TIniFile *file = new TIniFile("name.ini");

    file->WriteInteger("Something", "something", something);

    delete file;
}
```

Этот класс TIniFile основан на API, который уже сильно устарел, поэтому в последних версиях Windows может и не работать или работать неправильно.

Comment: Прекрасно работает. Пользуюсь постоянно.

Comment: Да, работает на вин7 сп1 отлично.